# Is this the correct way to localize a python app

Tags: python, localization, translation

So, I have a python app which I would like to translate in a few languages. The way the app loads its messages is by using a messages.py module and a few classes like for a example.

```
class MenuMessages:
    hello_world = "This is a menu"
```

The app will use a user defined settings (which I can query through the database) too choose which language the user wants to use the app on.

This app serves more than one user at once (so its not an app which is run by a single user).

An example function would be something as follow

```
import MenuMessages from messages

def connect():
    """Example function"""
    config = get_config(args)

    ## Way to check user lang settings
    language = config.get("lang", "en")

    ## Right now default messages
    print(MenuMessages.hello_world)
```

One idea that I have is to make a folder (lets call it languages) and put the same messages.py file structure, translate them and call them english.py, spanish.py etc

My issue with this is that I would need to find a way to switch between them everytime in a method given the user settings such as.

```
from languages.english import MenuMessages as en_menu_messages
from languages.spanish import MenuMessages as sp_menu_messages

def connect():
    """Example function"""
    config = get_config(args)

    ## Way to check user lang settings
    lang = config.get("lang", "en")

    if lang == "en":
        MenuMessages = en_menu_messages
    elif lang == "sp":
        MenuMessages = sp_menu_messages

    ## Right now default messages
    print(MenuMessages.hello_world)
```

Do you guys think this is a efficient way to approach this issue?

I want to implement it in the best way possible so I do not have to change it in the future.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in this code I see one problem - `MenuMessages` is local variable which exists only inside `connect` and you would have to use `return MenuMessages` or `global MenuMessages`

Comment: Python has standard module [gettext - Multilingual internationalization services](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/gettext.html)

Comment: [multi language support in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271733/multi-language-support-in-python-script)

Comment: @furas I think my question title is a bit misleading. My question is about if this is the correct way to go or is there something more efficient. I do not really like this solution since I will need to implement it for every method etc.

Also gettext does not work for me since my strings are in the messages.py object. Maybe I can the structure if its worth it.

Edit: I changed my question title